# ODBC: Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: mysql, odbc, squirrel-sql

I'm trying to make a connection to a sql server on a local lan but I keep getting the following error,

sqlTest: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLDriverConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.fw.sql.SQLDriverManager.getConnection(SQLDriverManager.java:133)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.execute(OpenConnectionCommand.java:97)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.ConnectToAliasCommand$SheetHandler.run(ConnectToAliasCommand.java:281)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.ConnectToAliasCommand$SheetHandler.performOK(ConnectToAliasCommand.java:238)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.gui.db.ConnectionInternalFrame.connect(ConnectionInternalFrame.java:311)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.gui.db.ConnectionInternalFrame.access$300(ConnectionInternalFrame.java:56)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.gui.db.ConnectionInternalFrame$MyOkClosePanelListener.okPressed(ConnectionInternalFrame.java:461)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.gui.OkClosePanel.fireButtonPressed(OkClosePanel.java:148)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.gui.OkClosePanel.access$100(OkClosePanel.java:33)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.gui.OkClosePanel$1.actionPerformed(OkClosePanel.java:174)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.Main$1.dispatchEvent(Main.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'm running SQuirreL SQL Client Version 3.2.1 as administrator on Windows 7 x64 using JRE 1.6 u27.

I try to connect to SQL server 5.1 on ubuntu 10.04.

My connection settings,

[image]

Not sure if it's the url or what.  Also I tried to connect while wireshark was monitoring and it didn't pick up any packets.

Comment: ODBC bridge is to connect to ODBC data sources, not MySQL (which is what I think you meant when you said SQL server 5.1).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use ODBC-JDBC bridge?

I think you should use native JDBC drivers. If you use MySQL then connect string to your database may be like:

```
jdbc:mysql://10.11.12.1:3306/mybase
```